# UINavigationBar Text Color in Swift

Tags: text, colors, navigation, uinavigationbar, swift

How would I go about changing the color of the `UINavigationBar` in Swift?

Most things online say to do something like:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Which I translated to

```
let titleDict: NSDictionary = ["NSForegroundColorAttributeName": UIColor.whiteColor()]
self.navigationController.navigationBartitleTextAttributes = titleDict
//self is referring to a UIViewController
```

But it doesn't work.  I already changed the background and button colors, but the text color doesn't change.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` as key, not `"NSForegroundColorAttributeName"` string.

```
let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict
```

Comment: As per Swift 1.2 update, the syntax needs to be this `let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]`

Comment: As per Swift 2.2: `let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as? [String : AnyObject]`

Answer (score 38):

You can also change all `UINavigationController` appearances in your app within the `AppDelegate.swift` file. Just put the following code within the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function:

```
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.YourNavigationButtonsColor()  // Back buttons and such
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.YourBackgroundColor()  // Bar's background color

navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.YourTitleColor()]  // Title's text color
```

Creds: [Coderwall's Blog Post](https://coderwall.com/p/dyqrfa/customize-navigation-bar-appearance-with-swift)

Comment: Thank you for having comments next to the tint / bar tint color, that helped me realize what I was doing wrong, and thus ended the banging my head against a wall cycle.  :D

Answer (score 35):

**Swift 3+**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

Comment: Works, thanks! Unbelievably horrible though that you can't simply set an outlet or style in IB ... I find Nav Controllers to be hard enough to customize that I end up making my own top bar :/

Answer (score 28):

**Swift 2.0**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    //Nav Bar Title
    self.title = "WORK ORDER"
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], for: .selected)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.x:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use like:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
      navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

     return true
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.1:**

```
    let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let titleDict = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict
```