# UINavigationBar text colour stays white after pop

Tags: ios, swift

I am pushing a view controller on to my navigation controller that sets the navigation bar to have a transparent background and white text. When the view is popped, it should restore the navigation bar to what it used to look like - white background and black text. However, this isn't happening. My code for the view I am pushing:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

When I pop back to the root view controller, the colour of the title is white. This should be black instead. Why is this happening?

Comment: try to change `navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UINavigationBar Text Color in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402000/uinavigationbar-text-color-in-swift)

Comment: Use those codes of viewWillDisappear in viewWillAppear of the root view controller.

Comment: @AntonBelousov Already tried the "duplicate" answer, it doesn't work and still produces the same result. I've actually given up on this now and just put a `UILabel` in the `titleView` of the `navigationBar`

Answer (score 1):

Actually Antons suggestion is correct, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402000/uinavigationbar-text-color-in-swift) actually helped me to solved my problem, which had the same strange behaviour, but there's still one step to implement:

From the post you'll see that the following code is suggested:

```
 let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = (titleDict as! [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
```

But you need to remember to put this on the `viewDidLoad` function.

Hope it helps someone :)